# CoreBluetooth read NSData

Tags: nsarray, nsdata, converters

i try to read and write something in CoreBluetooth

So my device(peripheral) send me the lenght of a array
and the array as one.

I read the value with this method

```
(void)readValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic;
```

when i get the answer from the peripheral the

```
(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error;
```

is calling
When i read one value it is not a problem

```
char arrayLength;
```

`charakteristik.value getBytes:&arrayLength lenght:SERVICE_ARRAYLENGTH_LEN]`

`self.MyArrayLenght=(float)arrayLength;`-

But when i get the array from the Peripheral i dont know how to read them

charakteristik.value is NSData

when i trying to

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:charakteristik.value]
```

i got error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x4e, 0x49, 0x42, 0x41, 0x72, 0x63, 0x68, 0x69)'
```

The hex (0x4e, 0x49, 0x42, 0x41, 0x72, 0x63, 0x68, 0x69.......) are the data what i want to read and later show

How can i read the NSData? Or How i can convert the NSData to NSArray?

Edit:
Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the unarchived NSData object from the peripheral is incomplete. CoreBluetooth limits maximum size of a characteristic could update each time, which is set by the central device. The exceeded part would be truncated while transferring. Probably the size of your array exceeds the size limitation, thus the central device did not receive the compete one, which results in exception.

The maximum length limitation varies from device to device, you can get the size limitation from the *maximumUpdateValueLength* property of the CBCentral object given by the CBPeipheralManagerDelegate methods:

`- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral central:(CBCentral *)central didSubscribeToCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic`

`- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request`

`- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests`

or any other methods that offer a CBCentral object.

If you want to send over-sized data, you should segment the data into pieces and send them through a couple of times. On the central device, you could rebuild the original data object by combining the pieces together. Apple provides a sample code to illustrate how to send over-sized data. [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score -1):

Probably would have answered your question by now.

Just in case: you can read the NSData content with the method:

```
char *data = [NSData data];
```

The length of the data is retrieved with

```
[NSData length];
```

To check if it contains your data you can simply do something like:

```
strncmp(blah, [NSDataObject data], [NSDataObject length]);
```

Having said that, you can define which service you want to discover and only that one. You can then restrict even further to only listen to the particular characteristic you're interested with in

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
```

call

```
[peripheral discoverCharacteristics:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"ABCD"]] forService:service];
```

Hope this help